# Will the support for the API-Key based authorisation for asana end with Asana Connect?

Tags: api, oauth, asana

i am developing an internal tool for bugtracking at my company. My question is: Will the support for the api-key based authorisation stop with asana connect?

We know the adventages about OAuth. But we are only a few people and we dont really need the OAuth - based stuff. We would like to use the old API authorisation.

Any chance?

Greetings from Germany,

Karsten

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is a better choice for client applications, but for some cases (automated internal integration with SCM or bug management, etc., which it sounds like is the case you're talking about) the API key still makes sense.

If we ever deprecate the old API key, you can be sure we'll make it just as easy to get a one-off OAuth token for similar use cases.